# Disable multi touches for a drawing view

Tags: ios, uiview, touch

I have a view where I'm drawing lines. When I draw a line with two fingers or more, there is a weird behaviour. That's why I want to disable multi touch on this view.

I tried :

```
self.drawingView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
self.drawingView.exclusiveTouch = YES;
```

But there is no impact. And my the touches method are still called.
Ideally, I want to when I try to draw with two fingers, it does nothing. Is there a solution ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your touches methods (Began/Moved) check how many touches are on screen and there is only one touch, handle it, otherwise pass it along.  Example `touchesMoved`:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{


if ((touches.count == 1) && ([event allTouches].count == 1)) {
   // handle single finger touch moves here
    ....
} else {
    // If more than one touch, pass it along
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

}
```

}